# How to use the static int variable when dealing with args?

Tags: java, arrays, static, int, args

So we've been assigned to create a program that contains 5 methods. The user needs to input a number on the terminal and that number will be the common variable that will be used by all the methods.

I know that

> static int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0])

will be the line used to scan what number will be used. My problem comes from how exactly will I use said line. It gives me an error when I place it outside the main method and I cant use it for the non-main methods

Answer (score 0):

> static int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0])

You will get compile time error using this line because you cannot have a **local static variable**.

You should do this instead:

```
static int num; 
public static void main([]args){
    num  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

   // Then use num where you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You class should be something like

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter number");
     // this variable does not need to be static, local is better
     int myNum = scan.nextInt();
     Main main = new Main();
     main.method1 (myNum);
     main.method2 (myNum);
     main.method3 (myNum);
     main.method4 (myNum);
     main.method5 (myNum);
 }

private void method1(int myNum) {
}

// repeat for each new method
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't write that line outside the main method is because `args` is out of scope there. Therefore, what you should do is to *declare* `num` outside of `main`, then *assign* it inside `main`.

Outside `main`:

```
static int num;
```

Inside `main`:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```